# Write database rows to file in python

Tags: python

I am newbie in python I need a script do this:
there are a tables in my db; mytable1, mytable2,.. etc;

I want to write all rows in a table to file for each one of all tables,
Exmple:

```
mytable1:
col1  col2  col3  col4
val1  val2  val3  val4
mytable2:
col1  col2  col3  col4
val1  val2  val3  val4
val5  val6  val7  val8
```

my goal; when I run the script it will create files with table names and write rows comma separated, each row will be one line.

```
Output:
mytable1.txt
val1,val2,val3,val4

mytable2.txt
val1,val2,val3,val4
val5,val6,val7,val8
```

what is the most efficient way achieve this ?

```
          import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="..",
                     user="..",
                      passwd="..",
                      db="..")

cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ...")
result_set = cursor.fetchall()    
field_names = [val[0] for val in cursor.description]

with open('mytable1.txt', 'a') as f:
    for row in result_set:
       line = ','.join(row[field_name] for field_name in field_names)
       f.write(line)
```

Comment: @AswinMurugesh I just connected db and write it in foreach loop for each coluımns in row. But I know ther should be more easy and efficient way to make this, isn't it ?

Comment: Could you show some code? What DB are you using? Depending on the db type, there are different ways to do it efficiently.

Comment: @MartinE.Zulliger Edited, MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this, if you are using mysql.

```
cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE")
result_set = cursor.fetchall()    
field_names = [val[0] for val in cursor.description]

with open('mytable1.txt', 'a') as f:
    for row in result_set:
       line = ','.join(row[field_name] for field_name in field_names)
       f.write(line)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/untitled/Deneme.py", line 17, in <module>
    line = ','.join(row[field_name] for field_name in field_names)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, long found    HOW CAN I convert all these values to string ? cast in python ?

Comment: @MehmetYenerYILMAZ You can convert  like this: `str(variable_name)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python CSV library:

```
import csv

cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE")
result_set = cursor.fetchall()    
field_names = [val[0] for val in cursor.description]

f = file('table.txt', 'w')
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, field_names)
writer.writeheader()
for row in result_set:
    writer.writerow(row)
```